# Adding extra column when exporting Feature Importance

Tags: python, regression, export-to-csv, decision-tree

I am using .feature_importances_ to export the importance values from a regression tree model to a CSV. The tree is run multiple times with different numbers of variables. I am looking to add an extra column that lists the number of variables used when calculating the importance.

Currently I am able to export the importance values and variable names to a CSV with the code below

```
Importance = list(zip(model.feature_importances_,list(X)))
        Importance = pd.DataFrame(Importance,columns=["Importance","Feature_Name"])
        Importance.to_csv('File.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

and I get a CSV that looks like this

```
  Imp  VarName
0 1.00 0mm
0 0.58 0mm
1 0.42 0.63mm
0 0.54 0.63mm
1 0.36 0mm
2 0.10 0.125mm
```

What I am looking for is to add a 4th column with the number of variables used in that tree so the output would be like this

```
  Imp  VarName NumVar
0 1.00 0mm     1
0 0.58 0mm     2
1 0.42 0.63mm  2
0 0.54 0.63mm  3
1 0.36 0mm     3
2 0.10 0.125mm 3
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, I add a array of the size of the len with the value of the number of the len of X.

```py
import numpy as np

Importance = list(zip(model.feature_importances_, list(X), len(X) * np.ones(len(X))))
Importance = pd.DataFrame(Importance,columns=["Importance","Feature_Name", "NumVar"])
Importance.to_csv('File.csv')
```

When running for the first time, I think you can delete the append mode and the header to `False`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It was able to point me in the right direction. `len(X)*np.ones(len(X))` didn't quite work because it would only return 83 (the character count of the X variable list) Instead 

I was able to find np.full() and make it work with the following `np.full((Var_Count,1) , Var_Count)`